# Is the documentation for NSMergePolicyType wrong, or am I misunderstanding the descriptions?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Specifically, I'm wondering whether the definitions for `.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType` and `.mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType` are swapped.

**From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergepolicytype/1506860-mergebypropertyobjecttrumpmergep)** (emphasis mine):

> `mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType`: A policy that merges conflicts...by individual property, with *the external changes trumping in-memory changes*.

**My experiment:**

In a new iOS project:

1. I create two contexts sharing a persistent store coordinator - `main` and `background`. Each context's merge policy is set to `.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType` (same as description above).
2. In the model, I define a `Document` entity w/ a `name` attribute of type `String`/`NSString`.
3. I create and save a single instance, `documentA`, of `Document`.
4. In the `main` context, I fetch `documentA` and set its `name` to "main_document". I do not save.
5. In the `background` context, I fetch `documentA` and set its `name` to "background_document".
6. I save the `background` context.
7. The database's version of `documentA.name` (fetched w/ a external sqlite client) is now "background_document", as expected.
8. I save the `main` context.

This is where I encounter unexpected behavior, at least according to my reading of the documentation - The database's version of `documentA.name` is now "main_document".

If external changes should trump in-memory changes, **shouldn't the database's value still be set to "background_document"?**

Edit: If I switch each context's merge policy to `.mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType`, I get the behavior I'd expect from `.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType`'s description - Saving the `main` context discards `main`'s change.

Comment: WHAT THE HELL DOES `EXTERNAL CHANGES MEAN`? Drives me insane.

Comment: Not only are the definitions swapped, the _discussion_ is actually correct but you can only see it in the online docs, not in Xcode's docs. Highly inconsistent documentation unfortunately. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergebypropertyobjecttrumpmergepolicy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

They are correct in the framework header.

```
// This singleton policy merges conflicts between the persistent store's version of the object and the current in memory version. The merge occurs by individual property. For properties which have been changed in both the external source and in memory, the external changes trump the in memory ones.
@available(iOS 3.0, *)
public var NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy: AnyObject

// This singleton policy merges conflicts between the persistent store's version of the object and the current in memory version. The merge occurs by individual property. For properties which have been changed in both the external source and in memory, the in memory changes trump the external ones.
@available(iOS 3.0, *)
public var NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy: AnyObject
```